# Why is there a function undefined message whereas it's about variable

Tags: functional-programming, erlang, elixir

Let's say I'm invoking something like this

```
Enum.count(list)
```

And `list` is not defined in 'upper scope'. In most of languages you'll probably get something like `Variable list is undefined`, but in Elixir (it comes from Erlang, so I hope it's same behaviour) you'll be getting `undefined function list/0 (there is no such import)`.

1. What's the difference in Elixir from other (let's say imperative) programming languages in sense of distinction between variable and function?
2. Also I've noticed you can make a function in module, and if it takes zero arguments, you can call it without parentheses, I was wondering what's special about that. **(was answered below by @sabiwara)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elixir used to consider parentheses optional for all function calls, including 0-arity functions like `Kernel.node/0`:

```elixir
iex> node
:nonode@nohost
```

This behavior has since been [deprecated](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/syntax-reference.html#non-qualified-calls-local-calls) and will emit a compile time warning:

```elixir
warning: variable "node" does not exist and is being expanded to "node()", please use parentheses to remove the ambiguity or change the variable name
```

> Parentheses for non-qualified calls are optional, except for zero-arity calls, which would then be ambiguous with variables.

But since it would be a breaking change to just change this behavior, it still works and gets interpreted, in your case, as `list()`.

This might change in Elixir 2.0. A discussion on this topic [here](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/issues/5461).

Comment: In the example, `list` is certainly a variable. Question was why elixir tells me that `function is undefined`, when `list` is a variable, logically it should be something like `variable X is undefined`. Maybe there's something special in how elixir/erlang are treating variables. Would be grateful for help.

Comment: @pydem I don't get you. When you say "list is certainly a variable", how could Elixir know it, since "list" is not visible?

Comment: @pydem that's the whole point I was trying to make: the syntax being considered to be the same for `list` and `list()` (until a breaking change in Elixir 2.0 maybe), if there is no variable named `list` it will be interpreted as `list()`.

Comment: Also, this is not related to erlang, which is distinguishing between `CamelCase` for variables and `snake_case` for functions, and doesn't have optional parentheses.

Comment: Now it clicked! Thank you.